# Apps storing data in non-existent SD Card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, storage

I had a few encounters with apps corrupting because part of their data was somehow stored into my SD Card. So I decided to move everything back into internal memory, format the SD Card, un-mount it and remove it physically.

However, after removing the SD Card and restarting my phone, I noticed some peculiar behaviour. 3 of my apps immediately started "storing" data into my SD Card, which no longer exists physically. Skype stores 12kb, Messenger 28kb and 9gag 92kb.

I haven't tried re-updating the corrupted apps, not sure if they would try to "store" into the non-existent SD Card as well. Any explanations or knowledge on this behaviour?

EDIT: Adding in more details

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 2, below is a screenshot of my phone a few hours after removing my physical SD Card. The answer below further confuses me, as this "SD CARD" menu accessed through Settings > More > Application Manager was exactly what I used to manage which apps gets moved to the physical SD Card before I removed it. It remains the same after I mounted the SD Card back. Does this mean both emulated SD Card and physical SD Card information are combined in this menu?

[image]

Comment: Could it be they mean the *internal* (emulated) SD card? Hard to tell without knowing the device and seeing the source of your quote ;)

Comment: Would you please explain the point of accepting the edit [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/97529)?

Comment: that was actually me, I didn't know I was logged in differently, so I've added more info to confirm the answers

Comment: Please see http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know your phone model and features, so tried to explain it with my phone's system (Micromax A089). In my phone there is two internal memories. One called "System Storage" and the other called "Phone Storage or SD Card" (Not the external SD card inserted by me). I think your apps data is storing in the "Inbuilt Phone Storage/SD Card" of you phone. Otherwise there is no explanation for this problem.